# how to publish an existing article and save it to mediawiki Database

Tags: mediawiki

I am very much new to mediawiki, only a couple of days research. Here I already have an article called e.g., "sample" which I need to save it to mediawiki database which was installed on my wamp server (localhost). So how to achieve that? Should I need to write a  program for achieving it? Can anyone please help me in this?

Also, I have an HTML form and how to save that form to mediawiki DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use webservices to create an article and save it to your mediawiki database

here are some links ,pls refer to it.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CreateArticle

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CreateArticle/sourcecode

Comment: I can use web services , but  I am not able to get where to start and how to start.

Answer (score 0):

An API for manipulating wiki pages is available in core MediaWiki: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit

The HTML form cannot currently be stored in the DB unless it is adapted to work with wikitext.  This may change in the future.

Comment: Hi Mark,                                                                I don't want to manipulate wiki pages.I had an article in simple plain text e,g., SamplePage.doc, Here I want to save this SamplePage.doc in to mediawiki's DB.So I need info , whether It is possible or not. If yes,how can I do  that.